# Python Ray: How to share variable between workers?

Tags: python, caching, multiprocessing, ray

I am working on a pipeline that includes obtaining predictions from a machine learning model and I'm trying to use ray to speed it up. The inputs can get repetitive so I'd like to share a cache in the function such that all the workers of this remote function can a share access to the cache and search it and obtain values.
Something like the below

```py
@ray.remote
def f(x):
    # create inputs from x
    # do work
    unknown_y1 = []
    obtained_y1 = []
    for index, y in enumerate(y1):
        key = '|'.join([str(x) for x in y.values()])
        if key in cached:
            obtained_y1.append(cached[key])
        else:
            obtained_y1.append(np.inf)
            unknown_y1.append(promo)

    unknown_y2 = []
    obtained_y2 = []
    for index, y in enumerate(y2):
        key = '|'.join([str(x) for x in y.values()])
        if key in cached:
            obtained_y2.append(cached[key])
        else:
            obtained_y2.append(np.inf)
            unknown_y2.append(baseline)

    known_y1, known_y2 = predictor.predict(unknown_y1,unknown_y2)

    unknown_index = 0
    for index in range(len(y1)):
        if(obtained_y1[index] == np.inf):
            obtained_y1[index] = known_y1[unknown_index]
            key = '|'.join([str(x) for x in y1[index].values()])
            if not(key in cached):
                cached[key] = obtained_y1[index]
            unknown_index = unknown_index+1
    
    unknown_index = 0
    for index in range(len(y2)):
        if(obtained_y2[index] == np.inf):
            obtained_y2[index] = known_y2[unknown_index]
            key = '|'.join([str(x) for x in y2[index].values()])
            if not(key in cached):
                cached[key] = obtained_y2[index]
            unknown_index = unknown_index+1
```

I've tried creating a global dictionary by adding `global cached;cached=dict()` at the top of my script but it seems like that variable is a different version across workers and does not share the data. Previously I was doing this with `dogpile.cache.redis` but the region will not be serializable since it uses a thread lock. I've also tried creating a dict and putting it in ray's object store using `ray.put(cached)` but I think I read somewhere that ray [cannot share dictionaries in memory](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/6976)

I am currently trying to return the cache from each worker and merge them in the main and then put them in object store again.
Is there a better way of sharing a dictionary/cache between ray workers?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this question/answer about writing a function cache for Ray. [Implementing cache for Ray actor function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63379029/implementing-cache-for-ray-actor-function/63386596#63386596)

You have the right idea, but I think the key detail you're missing is that you should keep global state in an actor or object store (if it's immutable) with Ray.

In your case, it looks like you are trying to cache parts of your remote function, not the whole thing. You might want something that looks like this.

Here's a simplified version of how you may consider writing your function.

```
@ray.remote
class Cache:
  def __init__(self):
    self.cache = {}

  def put(self, x, y):
    self.cache[x] = y

  def get(self, x):
    return self.cache.get(x)

global_cache = Cache.remote()

@ray.remote
def f(x):
  all_inputs = list(range(x)) # A simplified set of generated inputs based on x
  obtained_output = ray.get([global_cache.get(i) for i in all_inputs])

  unknown_indices = []
  for i, output in enumerate(obtained_output):
    if output is None:
        unknown_inputs.append(i)
 
  # Now go through and calculate all the unknown inputs
  for i in unknown_inputs:
    output = predict(all_inputs[i]) # calculate the output
    global_cache.put.remote(output) # Cache it so it's available next time
    obtained_output[i] = output

  return obtained_output
```

Comment: Does the actor block? I remember when using `ray.get` in remote tasks, it would usually block and not run completely in parallel but I'm not sure if the same is for actors. I'll try this though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you did not create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so I cannot see how you are doing your multiprocessing. For the sake of argument, I will assume you are using the `Pool` class from the `multiprocessing` module (`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` as a similar facility). Then you want to use a *managed*, sharable `dict` as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


def init_pool(the_cache):
    # initialize each process in the pool with the following global variable:
    global cached
    cached = the_cache

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        cached = manager.dict()
        with Pool(initializer=init_pool, initargs=(cached,)) as pool:
            ... # code that creates tasks

# required by Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This creates in dictionary with variable `cached` a reference to a *proxy* for this dictionary. So all dictionary accesses become essentially more akin to remote procedure calls and therefore execute much more slowly than would a "normal" dictionary access. Just be aware ...

**If there is some other mechanism for creating workers (the decorator `@ray.remote`?), the `cached` variable can instead be passed as an argument to function `f`.**

Comment: Given that OP is using ray, it's probably safe to assume that they're calling f.remote(...) many times.